# @SpringBootApplication cannot be resolved to a type for Spring Boot version 2.0.3

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have created a project using Spring Initializr with Spring Boot V-2.0.3
I am using STS 3.9.4 on Ubuntu Machine.

I am getting these errors:

```
The import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication cannot be resolved

SpringBootApplication cannot be resolved to a type
```

I have already tried deleting the repository folder from .m2 folder and hitting the following commands

```
mvn clean dependency:tree
mvn clean compile
```

But still errors were not resolved than I added an Extra Dependency to the POM file

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I have updated the project by following the below steps after each step performed but still the error is not resolved.

```
STS Right click on project -> Maven -> Update Project
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to STS Right click on project -> Maven -> Update Project.